# Would a rocket whose mass doesn't decrease accelerate nonetheless?

Tags: acceleration, speed, rocket-science

Sorry if my question seems too elementary but I would like to know : according to Tsiolkovski equation, the speed of a rocket increases as its mass decreases, so the acceleration depends, to a certain extent on mass.

But what if the mass of the rocket didn't vary at all? What would happen when the exhausted matter (say, gaz or ions) reaches its maximum speed; Would the rocket speed increase anyway (but slower than a tsiolkovskian rocket) or would it remain constant (would its acceleration then be equal to zero)?

Comment: How will the mass stay the same?

Comment: A rocket that uses ambient fluid for working mass and therefore doesn't throw mass overboard is called a "jet"...

Comment: I think that the basic info you're interested in is all contained in the equation F=ma or a=F/m. If there is a net force F on the rocket due to the rocket engine, then the rocket will accelerate. If the mass m of the rocket is decreasing and the net force F due to the rocket engine remains the same, then the rocket will accelerate even more. Need to clarify your question if you are asking for info beyond this.

Comment: A solar powered fan accelerates stuff. No loss of mass required.

Comment: @dmckee -- his question wasn't an example of a rocket that worked this way (and even jets actually do throw mass overboard when burning it in the jet engine to heat the air) -- it was whether the speed of a rocket would still increase without its mass decreasing...

Comment: @MureyTasroc That's not an answer *because* it doesn't directly address the question, but the OP needs a reference to be able to reason about the subject. And while thermal turbine jets throw mass overboard that's a implementation detail: cephlapods are jet propelled and don't throw any mass overboard.

Comment: The constance of the mass is purely hypothetical (but it  came to my mind while thinking about what I think I understood concerning ionic propulsion (very little, that is), where I believe mass loss is less crucial to acceleration (take  than in hypergolic propulsion). Thank you Murey Tasroc and Samuel Weir, I suspected Newton's principle to be the answer but I wasn't so sure. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

> But what if the mass of the rocket didn't vary at all?

It must decrease if there is to be thrust.  The basic principle of a rocket is that thrust is generated by expelling mass.  From the Wikipedia article [Rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket):

> A rocket (from Italian rocchetto "bobbin") is a missile,
>   spacecraft, aircraft or other vehicle that obtains thrust from a
>   rocket engine. Rocket engine exhaust is formed entirely from
>   propellant carried within the rocket before use.  Rocket engines
>   work by action and reaction and push rockets forward simply by
>   expelling their exhaust in the opposite direction at high speed, and
>   can therefore work in the vacuum of space.

Answer (score 0):

If the mass doesn't change, you would be taking the logarithm of unity, which is 0, which means that the right-hand side of the equation is 0, which means that the left-hand side of the equation is also 0. But the left-hand side of the equation is the change in velocity, so there would be no change in velocity, that is, no acceleration.